# Excel switch case with globbing

Tags: excel

I have one column of encoded values like this:

```
60BM1
90CM2
120MM3
60CM1
120BM2
```

I want to convert the format according to this formula I created:

```
="F" & SWITCH(A1, "60*", "1", "90*", "2", "120*", "3") &
 "T" & "." & SWITCH(A1, "*BM*", "1", "*CM*", "2", "*MM*", "3") &
 "." & SWITCH(A1, "*1", "1", "*2", "2", "*3", "3")
```

to generate the new column's values

```
F.1.T.1.1
F.2.T.2.2
F.3.T.3.3
F.1.T.2.1
F.3.T.1.2
```

But the SWITCH functions don't work. Probably because of the wildstar `*`s.

How can I perform this kind of pattern-based substitution in excel?

Answer (score 1):

Use MATCH instead:

```
="F."&MATCH(LEFT(A1,2),{"60","90","12"},0)&".T."&MATCH(MID(A1,LEN(A1)-2,2),{"BM","CM","MM"},0)&"."&RIGHT(A1)
```

[image]